# Problems with QTest::mouseClick on QListWidget

Tags: qtestlib

I am trying to use QTest to do some testing. I have a QListWidget that I would like to click on to get a selection.  But after the click, nothing is selected. Does anyone have any ideas?

Here is my test class

```
void TestGui::List() {
    TestDialog dlg;
    dlg.show ();

    // Click on the centre of the second object
    QListWidget *list = dlg.ListWidget ();
    QListWidgetItem *item = list->item ( 1 );
    QRect rect = list->visualItemRect ( item );
    QTest::mouseClick ( list, Qt::LeftButton, 0, rect.center() );

    // Check if something was selected
    QCOMPARE ( list->currentRow (), 1 );
    QVERIFY ( list->currentItem () != NULL );
    QCOMPARE ( list->currentItem ()->text (), QString ( "Two" ) );
}
```

Below is the testing class

```
class TestGui: public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT

private slots:
    void List();
};
```

And here is the TestDialog class used to display the problem

```
class TestDialog : public QDialog {
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    TestDialog ( QWidget *parent = NULL )
    : QDialog ( parent, Qt::CustomizeWindowHint | Qt::WindowCloseButtonHint ) {
        QVBoxLayout *layout = new QVBoxLayout ( this );

        m_list = new QListWidget ( this );
        m_list->addItem ( "One" );
        m_list->addItem ( "Two" );
        m_list->addItem ( "Three" );
        m_list->addItem ( "Four" );
        layout->addWidget ( m_list );

        QPushButton *close_button = new QPushButton( "Close" );
        connect ( close_button, SIGNAL ( clicked () ), this, SLOT ( close () ) );
        layout->addWidget ( close_button );

        setWindowTitle( "Test" );
    }

    QListWidget *ListWidget ( void ) {
        return m_list;
    };

private:
    QListWidget *m_list;

}; // TestDialog
```

Answer (score 11):

After some more thought, it turns out that the click needs to be on the view widget and not the list itself.  So the line should look like this

QTest::mouseClick ( list->viewport (), Qt::LeftButton, 0, rect.center() );

Thanks

Comment: Brilliant! This still works in september 2017 (i use PyQt5 btw)

Comment: It also still works in octover 2017. However, it doesn't work with double clicks...

Comment: many thanks for that! I struggled looking for the reason why it didn't work!